# how to get twitter metrics? Is there any twitter API for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I want to detect most influential tweets and twitter accounts for a specific topic. I need to get metrics like retweet_count, link_click_count(if contains), media_count(if_contains), tweet_show_count, tweet_mention_count, replied_count etc.

I do not know if I should calculate influence ratio by a formula OR directly get calculated engagements and impressions of a specific tweet by using any API?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for tweepy: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy. It's pretty fun to work with.

Comment: yes I am using tweepy for getting tweets, user accounts and any other stuff but how about analytics data? How can I calculate the impression of a specific tweet?